# Accessing dom elements in angular in an angular way

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a usecase where I want to access the dom element by its id and set some value in it.

I achieved it using

```
<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('test_id')).value = '123';
```

We are using third party api where we dont have any control over test_id that is test_id is not set up by us.

I want to know is there any angular way to avoid accessing element by document.getElementById?

If the test_id is in our control then we can use @ViewChild but here we can not use. So is there any way so that I can access the element by id in an angular way?

Comment: I don't get where `we dont have any control over test_id` means the solution is `element by id in an angular way`.. do you mind explaining in a bit more detail?

Comment: We can set <div #test_id ></div> and then access that one using @ViewChild in ts. But here as we are using external dom snippet where we only know that <div id='test_id'> after inspecting that element but that code is not at our end meaning we can only see that div after inspecting (we are not creating or setting it in our application)

Comment: so you want to view this div that you didn't make? you can just take `div.outerHTML` value and put it in an html parser to view how you want ig?

Comment: How are you determining whether a particular method is "in an angular way"?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Angular way means use of directive or renderer or ElementRef

Answer (score -1):

```
  element: HTMLElement;
  this.element = document.getElementById('test_id') as HTMLElement;
```

Comment: This code is the same as the OPs, just with the cast after the function call.